# how can I make curser disappear when button is clicked in android

Tags: java, android, cursor, android-cursor

I am trying to make the blinking cursor disappear when the button is clicked in android, and I have no idea how to do than, can anyone help with that.

Comment: Move the keyboard focus to another component. In Java Swing you would run the requestFocus() method of this other component.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4222206/hiran-chaudhuri how to use that, I try to do that it diverts the cursor to the last TextEdit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `setCursorVisible` attribute to `false`

```kotlin
editText.setCursorVisible(false);
```

on Button click.